# How do I connect an input to the Side chain in Final Cut Pro X?

Tags: audio, final-cut-pro

I noticed Final Cut's compressor plugin does have a Side Chain option.

From apps like Ableton Live I know that you can usually connect a source to a side-chain input that controls parameters affecting the main signal.

Unfortunately I have not find any documentation how to do this in FCP

[image: Compress or UI in Final Cut Pro X]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That compressor's just straight out of Logic Pro. I bet no-one thought about FCP not having distinct busses you could sidechain from. I do love how the manual describes the parameters, though ;)) Sidechain tracks/busses should be listed top right… but not in FCP

In short, this is not possible.

[image]

Comment: Well, it's not the answer that I've been waiting for - but it seems it's the right answer, so thanks :)

Comment: Welcome - sorry I didn't have better news. Google seemed pretty limited on it, but I did find a couple of user forums confirming it. Maybe they just expect everybody on FCP also has Logic they can throw projects out to… or maybe they just never thought it through & re-used the exact same plugin [still amuses me the FCP manual gives details for all the parameters, yet fails to notice you can't actually connect it to anything :\